# Remote Desktop Services in Azure

Tags: azure

I'm in the proccess for deploying a RDS environment for a customer, and I've thought it could be better (faster, cheaper and more secure) for my client if I could implement it using Windows Azure hosted Virtual machines than having onpremise hardware.

Then, my questions are:

· Is it possible technically? I mean, will the virtual machine give good service for, let's say, +-100 concurrent users? Will it be a consistent connection without break-downs?

· Is it possible legally? That is, can I do it? I suppose I should buy RDS licenses... but I don't know how nor where to do it.

· I'm I right? I mean, is this the best solution to use Azure?

I've found some information so far (here, for example: http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/enabling-remote-desktop-services-in.html) but I'm not sure about the "official" answer for theese questions

Thanks in advance for your help,

luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Technically possible*: Yes
- *Good service for +/- 100 concurrent users?* This will depend on the size of your VM. Large VMs have a higher bandwidth. More info: [7 Things to Know About Windows Azure Capacity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud/gg663909.aspx)
- *Will it be a consistent connection without break-downs?* Will depend on the instance size... if you choose a small instance and it's constantly at 100% CPU and Network I/O you won't have a stable environment. Besides that you have to know that today "Virtual Machines" is still a preview feature without SLA.
- *Is it possible legally?* I'm not sure actually...Take a look at the licensing terms: [MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 R2 (FOR USE WITH WINDOWS AZURE)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206791). These state the following:

> You may not use the following functionality in the software:
>
> - Remote Desktop Services
> - Rights Management Services

- *I suppose I should buy RDS licenses?* You should [contact support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) and ask if you CAN use RDS in Windows Azure, and if that's allowed you can simply buy these licenses (CAL) from Microsoft Partners.
- *Is this the best solution to use Azure?* Well this depends. If your customer wants this today I would say no (Amazon might be a better pick today). The reason is simple, Virtual Machines is still a preview feature and imho this isn't suited for production deployments (yet).